# iOS Swift SpriteKit: How to make a child spritenode's position and movements to be the same as its parent spritenode?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, coordinate-systems

I want to implement a spritenode with a "colored highlight". The "highlight can be of a number of colors. This is done in sandbox app to try things out.

I have considered using SKTextures to represent the "highlight" of the node. However, with this method, I will have to upload a number of "highlight" files which must be "pre-attached" to the host spritenode png file. So, if I have 5 spritenode "host" png files and 5 "highlight" png files, then I will have a total of 5x5=25 png files that represents all the possible combinations. That will be way too many files to prepare and maintained.

So, I rather make the spritenode "host" have a child spritenode which is the highlight.

Both the host and highlight spritenode need to move together and the highlight spritenode is 1 zPosition infront of the "host" spritenode. So, the cgposition of the 2 spritenodes should be the same.

I create a Class file for the host spritenode.

```
class Host : SKSpriteNode {

    var highlight = SKSpriteNode()
        init(strPieceName : String) { 
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: strPieceName)
        super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clear, size: texture.size())

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func addHighlight(withColour strColour : String) {

        highlight = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: strColour)
        addChild(highlight)
    }        
}
```

In the GameScene class, I call the addHighlight function in touchesBegan

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for t in touches {

        let cgPointTouched = t.location(in: self)
        let skNodeTouched : SKNode = self.atPoint(cgPointTouched)
        switch skNodeTouched.name {
        case "Highlight":
         host.highlight.position = skNodeTouched.position
         host.highlight.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
         host.highlight.size = CGSize(width: 0.2, height: 0.2)
         host.highlight.alpha = 1
         host.highlight.zPosition = 3
         addChild(host.highlight)
    }
    }
 }
```

The problem with this code is that although the highlight spritenode "follows" the host spritenode, the screen appearance of the position of highlight spritenode is not "on top" of the host spritenode. But strangely, the cgposition of the 2 spritenodes are the same.

I think it has something to coordinates systems of the GameScene and the Highlight class not being the same but I cannot figure out how to solve this and why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you are doing all this complicated stuff,  but you are not suppose to touch the position.  Leave it at 0,0, and never add it to the scene. Instead leave it on the sprite, and it will always follow your sprite.

Of course, you can always use `colorBlendFactor` to blend the sprite color with your texture to create the highlight

Your class should look like this:

```
class Host : SKSpriteNode {

    var highlight : SKSpriteNode!

    func addHighlight(withColour strColour : String) {
        highlight.removeFromParent()
        highlight = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: strColour)
        //highlight.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        highlight.size = CGSize(width: 0.2, height: 0.2)
        //highlight.alpha = 1
        highlight.zPosition = 3

        highlight.moveToParent(self)
    }        

}
```

There is no need to add extra inits that do exactly the same thing as other inits

Your touch code should look like this:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for t in touches {

        let cgPointTouched = t.location(in: self)
        let skNodeTouched : SKNode = self.atPoint(cgPointTouched)
        switch skNodeTouched.name {
            case "Highlight":
            host.addHighlight(withColour:"whatevermycoloris")
        }
    }
 }
```

Of course, you can always avoid the extra node by just doing:

```
class Host : SKSpriteNode {

    func addHighlight(withColour : UIColor) {
        color = withColour
        colorBlendFactor = 0.75 //Change this intensity to 1 to add more color
    }        

}
```

> 

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for t in touches {

        let cgPointTouched = t.location(in: self)
        let skNodeTouched : SKNode = self.atPoint(cgPointTouched)
        switch skNodeTouched.name {
            case "Highlight":
            host.addHighlight(withColour:UIColor.yellow)
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: The `colorBlendFactor` did not give the effect I wanted but it was worth a try. Thanks.

Comment: The `SKSpriteNode` method, had 2 issues, one the position of the highlight node was still not align with the position of the Host node. So I change the `addHighlight()` function to accept a position parameter and I passed the cgposition of the `skNodeTouched`. This solve the position issue. The second issue was that the Highlight node always appear 'on top' of the Host node no matter what zPosition I used. I want the highlight node to be 'behind' the host node. Thank you.

Comment: what and what?  You did not specify either of that in your question

Comment: if the position is not aligned with your Host node, then your host node is jacked up, because it is literally suppose to hang over your Host node,  I suggest fixing your host.  If you want the highlight to be behind your host (Then you aren't highlighting it) make the zPosition -1

Comment: now I am reading this again,  you passed the cgPointTouched to your highlight?  That would mean your highlight is on the scene and not on the host like I told you to do

Comment: The zPosition = -1 will make the highlight node stay 'behind' the Host node. That works. The zPosition of the Host node is 4. If I make the zPosition of the Highlight node = 3 or 2 or 1, the Highlight node will still appear 'infront' of the Host node. Why is this happening? Why -1 works but positive values less than the Host zPosition does not? Thank you

Comment: zPosition is relative to the parent.  If your Host is 4, then -1 on highlight makes it 3